# Can you define a NULL on a column definition in the Create Table statement in a Firebird DB?

Tags: firebird, firebird2.1, sql

I am using [SQL Manager Lite](http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products/ibfb/manager/download) to try to run a DDL Create Table script. I am new to Firebird and I don't know why it isn't working.  The following script...

```
create table Contacts (
    ID                      integer            not null,
    FirstName               varchar(64)        not null,
    LastName                varchar(64)        not null,
    MiddleInitial           varchar(1)             null
);
```

Is causing a parsing error (UNIDENTIFIED TOKEN) on the null constraint for the MiddleInitial column.

Here is the exact error returned by Sql Lite...

```
Invalid token.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Token unknown - line 5, column 52.
Null.
```

Is the NULL constraint not allowed in Create Table DDL for firebird?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it works, as I can't test it right now, but try removing `null` from the statement:

```
CREATE TABLE Contacts(
    Id integer not null,
    First_Name varchar(64) not null,
    Last_Name varchar(64) not null,
    Middle_Initial varchar(1)
);
```

See this link:
[CREATE DATABASE](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref25/fblangref25-ddl-tbl.html#fblangref25-ddl-tbl-create)

Comment: That was it.  The Null is not allowed.

By the way...I also learned that you can't name a field Active without delimiting with quotes.

Seth

Answer (score 0):

Null is not allowed but by default it's null

You can take a look at [this grammar](http://www.ibphoenix.com/main.nfs?a=ibphoenix&page=parse5)